# Allure: How to rerun all Broken Tests and then generate report

Tags: maven, testing, allure

I have about 150 tests. When I run them all I always have about 2-5% of broken tests, and there are always different tests...

What I want: Run tests once, and if there were broken tests maven reruns them and then I  can re-generate report with changes:it would be only Passed and Failed tests

Is it possible?
What should I start from?

I  use Java+Maven+JUnit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allure doesn't run your tests, it is only display the test results. So you have few options to rerun your failed tests:

- Use `rerunFailingTestsCount` option from `maven surefire plugin`. If this option set surefire will rerun failing tests immediately after they fail. See [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#rerunFailingTestsCount) for more details.
- Use custom jUnit retry rule in your flaky tests:

  ```
  public class RetryRule implements TestRule {

      private int attempts;
      private int delay;
      private TimeUnit timeUnit;

      public RetryRule(int attempts, int delay, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
          this.attempts = attempts;
          this.delay = delay;
          this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
      }

      @Override
      public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {
          return new Statement() {
              @Override
              public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                  Throwable e = null;
                  for (int i = 0; i <= attempts; i++) {
                      try {
                          base.evaluate();
                          return;
                      } catch (Throwable t) {
                          Thread.sleep(timeUnit.toMillis(delay));
                      }
                  }
                  throw e;
              }
          };
      }
  }
  ```

  And add it to each flaky test:

  ```
  @Rule
  public RetryRule retryRule = new RetryRule(2, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

  You can find more information about jUnit rules [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean duplicate tests after re-run from Allure report then you can refer to this repo - still in progress but basic functionality is working fine. For now it cleans duplicate tests which are generated by TesnNG + Allure!!

https://github.com/Esprizzle/allure-report-processor